# git pull does not automatically merge my changes

Tags: git

I use git to install prezto. I made a 1 line change in zshrc.
And then I do a 'git pull && git submodule update --init --recursive'

But I got a merge conflict:

Here is the diff:

```
$ git diff
diff --cc runcoms/zshrc
index 2091d75,039b882..0000000
--- a/runcoms/zshrc
+++ b/runcoms/zshrc
@@@ -11,5 -11,3 +11,8 @@@ if [[ -s "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprezto/in
  fi

  # Customize to your needs...
++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +setopt noEXTENDED_GLOB
 +
++=======
++>>>>>>> 3c47c57c872f9d448ef79249b873e164fb5028e2
```

My understanding is Git see my one 1 change ("between <<<< and ===) and there is nothing from remote (blank between ===== and >>>>).

My question is why Git does not automatically merge my changes?

Comment: git cannot automatically merge because it detected a conflict. You should fix this conflict and then commit again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to say what is causing the issue from a 2 way diff.  You can see the problem one of two ways.

Presuming you have a suitable mergetool configured

```
git mergetool
```

Should pull up a 3 way diff so you can see the base as well as their modification.

Alternately, you can instruct git to embed all three forms in the diff output

```
git config --global merge.conflictstle diff3
```

You may need to abort and rerun the merge to get this change to show up

One way this problem can occur is if there was a line at the base version that was modified by your and deleted by them.

Answer (score 0):

Git saw that you have a unmerged diff. You need to do this merge manually and after this commit and continue - if you use rebase.

Step by step:

1. First modify file to take correct content (make merge manuallly)
2. After `git commit`
3. `git pull`
4. `git push with modif`